# Можно ли сказать "до удивления мало"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "до удивления мало"? Только что услышала это выражение по ТВ (канал ОТР, 5-45, диктор за кадром). По-моему, автор смешал два оборота: "до смешного мало" и "на удивление мало"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше сказать "удивительно мало" или "на удивление мало". Вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в смешении разрешенных и неразрешенных оборотов, а в их разной грамматике.

(1)На удивление мало, на удивление много - направленный В.п. указывает характер эмоций. Синонимичные выражения - удивительно мало и удивительно много, но они в менее экспрессивны.

Например: Но машин в городе на удивление мало. Возле фонтана, традиционного места встречи людей на выставке, было на удивление мало народа.

(2) Есть выражение "до удивления много", но нет выражения "до удивления мало". Дело в том, что предлог ДО задает движение снизу вверх, от нейтрального состояния до удивления. Ему СООТВЕТСТВУЕТ нарастание количества - от меньшего к большему.

Например: Народу набралось до удивления много, не одна, пожалуй, сотня,

Comment: Спасибо за тонкий логический анализ русских предлогов.  Но в языке, помимо логики, безусловно необходимой при формировании индивидуальной речи, существуют готовые устойчивые словосочетания. Их смешивание является речевой ошибкой, часто такие ошибки звучат комично, их очень любят использовать сатирики. Благодаря существованию телевидения придумки сатириков могут становиться частью общерусского языка. Например: «Молчит, как рыба об лёд» уже пора вносить в словари.

Comment: Я не против устойчивых сочетаний, просто иногда хочется понять, почему они стали таковыми. Впрочем, это интересно не всем, поэтому можно считать, что вы правы и автор смешал два оборота.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, предлоги ДО и НА характеризуют динамику явлений. Пример: Ожидал, что много, а оказалось на удивление мало. Здесь явление состоялось и пришлось только констатировать его состояние. Другое дело с ДО удивления мало. Здесь происходит процесс ожидания. Ожидается мало, может быть, даже еще меньше, но чтобы вышло та-ак мало... Вот здесь - ДО удивления.